# VS Code plugin to export and import watch variables by order

Tags: plug-in, visual-studio-code

When practicing coding challenges (e.g LeetCode), particularly when learning from other's solutions, I like running the code in VS Code and watch local variables and expressions in the Watch panel (I completely ignore the Variables panel).

Is there a VS code plugin that enables exporting and importing watched variables and expressions, and does so by order of their "declaration" in the Watch panel?